# How do I make a edit button in a template for a grid in KendoUI?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

My basic question is 'How do I create a button in the template that will turn on edit mode in a KendoGrid?'
I have the following kendoui template:

```
  <script id="serviceGridRowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
            <tr>
                <td><span data-bind="text: sequence"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: service"></span></td>
                 <td><input data-role="datepicker" data-bind="xpressdate: from_date"/></td>
                @*<td><span data-bind="xpressdate: from_date" data-dateformat="MM/dd/yyyy"></span></td>*@
                <td><span data-bind="xpressdate: to_date" data-dateformat="MM/dd/yyyy"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: provider"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: name"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: status" ></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: deny_cd" ></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="xpressdate: add_date" data-dateformat="MM/dd/yyyy"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: add_init" ></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="xpressdate: change_date" data-dateformat="MM/dd/yyyy"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: change_init" ></span></td>
                    <td><button >Turn on Edit</button></td>


            </tr>
```

I have tried to binding to a command but it doesn't like it. I can easily have a datapicker in this row but I want to have just text and then either click on an edit button or as it was before I created the template just clicking on a row starts the edit.
Just for reference here is the div with the grid.

```
 <div data-role="grid"
                     data-bind="source: referralData.Services"
                     data-scrollable="true"
                     data-row-template="serviceGridRowTemplate"
                     data-editable="{mode:'inline',template:serviceEditTemplate}"
                     data-resizable="true"
                     data-toolbar="['create', 'Print']"
                     data-columns="[
                                     { 'field': 'sequence', 'width': 70, 'title': 'Sequence #' },
                                     { 'field': 'service',width:70,title:'Service' },
                                     { 'field': 'from_date', 'width': 70, 'title': 'Effective Date' },
                                     { 'field': 'to_date', 'width': 70, 'title': 'End Date' },
                                     { field:'provider','title': 'Provider',width:70 },
                                     { 'field': 'name', 'title': 'Provider Name' },
                                     { 'field': 'status', 'width': 180, 'title': 'Service Status Code' },
                                     { 'field': 'deny_cd', 'width': 180, 'title': 'Service Reason Code' },
                                     { 'field': 'add_date', 'width': 70, 'title': 'Add Date' },
                                     { 'field': 'add_init', 'width': 70, 'title': 'Added By' },
                                     { 'field': 'change_date', 'width': 70, 'title': 'Modified Date' },
                                     { 'field': 'change_init', 'width': 80, 'title': 'Modified By' },
                    { command: 'edit' }
                                  ]"

                     style="width:100%; height:auto"></div>
```

One last note, xpressdate is just a custom data picker that is needed for weird formatted dates coming from the db.

Anyone know of an example or how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a couple of small things.  First off, in the rowTemplate include data-uid="#=uid#" on the tr.

```
<tr data-uid="#= uid #">
```

Then inside the rowTemplate, add this as an edit button

```
<td><a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-edit" href="\#"><span class="k-icon k-edit"></span>Edit</a></td>
```

That should include a fully kendo grid styled edit button that should switch that particular gridrow into edit mode.

See sample http://jsbin.com/soqet/1/edit

Comment: This solved my problem and so I marked it as the answer. However, do you know what needs to be done now to make the update button work?

Comment: I think the main issue is that when you use inline editing, it doesn't use the editTemplate.  I can add some simple characters for a test, and they don't show up in the inline editing, but do on popup editing.  So there is something going on with that.